# correct syntax for private temporary table with on commit clause

Tags: oracle, commit, private, temporary

I am creating a private temporary table in oracle with the following

```
    create private temporary table ora$ptt_users as
select * from lul_users;
```

This works fine however when I add on commit preserve definition as follows

```
    create private temporary table ora$ptt_users as
select * from lul_users on commit preserve definition;
```

I get an "SQL command not properly ended.
Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the clause in the wrong place:

```
create private temporary table ora$ptt_users
on commit preserve definition as
select * from lul_users;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KiyFOLYR) (against `dual`).

See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6__I2149006), including [the example for a global temporary table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6__I2153132)